# Join to leftJoin queries in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I have a query that Im trying to retrieve. Its suppose to get a listings information with its trips and location details.

This is how Im calling the query inside the Destinations controller:

```
public function destinations($id) {

        $destination = Destination::findOrFail($id);

        $listingGuides = Listing::findGuidesTrips($destination)
            ->with('locations')
            ->withCount('trips')
            ->get(); 

         return view('destinations.index', compact('listingGuides');

}
```

And the `findGuidesTrips` method is inside the Listings Model:

```
 public static function findGuidesTrips($destination) {

        $query = self::query()
            ->leftJoin('trips', 'listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')
            ->addSelect(
                \DB::raw('listings.name,listings.slug,listings.type,listings.id,MIN(trips.cost) as starting_price')
            )
            ->groupBy('listings.id');

        $query = self::query()
            ->leftJoin('locations', 'listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')
            ->addSelect(
                \DB::raw('locations.longitude as longitude')
            )->addSelect(
                \DB::raw('locations.latitude as latitude')
            );

        $query = $query->whereHas('locations',function($query) use ($destination) {
            $query->where('region', 'like', $destination->location)->orWhere('country', $destination->location);

        });

        return $query;
    }
```

This is what I get back:

[image]

As you can see, I have 2  $query = self::query() quires, but only one is being called (the bottom one). Its ignoring the top self::query.

I was just wondering how would I go about combining these 2 leftJoin queries into one perhaps? Or is there a better way of doing this query?

( I tried doing this: )

```
$query = self::query()
            ->leftJoin('trips', 'listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')
            ->addSelect(
                \DB::raw('listings.name,listings.slug,listings.type,listings.id,MIN(trips.cost) as starting_price')
            )
            ->leftJoin('locations', 'listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')
            ->addSelect(
                \DB::raw('locations.longitude as longitude')
            )->addSelect(
                \DB::raw('locations.latitude as latitude')
            )->groupBy('listings.id');
```

But it gives me `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'listing_id' in on clause is ambiguous` error

Comment: At a glance, just note that you can specify the table name on `->leftJoin()` functions, like `->leftJoin('trips', 'trips.listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')` or `->leftJoin('locations', 'locations.listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')`; That would get rid of your ambiguity issue.

Comment: Try `trips.listing_id` for first and `locations.listing_id` for second in place of `listing_id` in last query.

Comment: @TimLewis Nice job man, didn't think about that. yes that returns exactly what I wanted! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Niklesh that work perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Tim Lewis and @Niklesh, all I had to do was:

`trips.listing_id` for first query and `locations.listing_id` for second.

Here is the final query:

```
public static function findGuidesTrips($destination) {

        $query = self::query()
            ->leftJoin('trips', 'trips.listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')
            ->addSelect(
                \DB::raw('listings.name,listings.slug,listings.type,listings.id,MIN(trips.cost) as starting_price')
            )
            ->leftJoin('locations', 'locations.listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')
            ->addSelect(
                \DB::raw('locations.longitude as longitude')
            )->addSelect(
                \DB::raw('locations.latitude as latitude')
            )->groupBy('listings.id');

        $query = $query->whereHas('locations',function($query) use ($destination) {
            $query->where('region', 'like', $destination->location)->orWhere('country', $destination->location);

        });

        return $query;
    }
```